# Data comparison tool broken by date input request:

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I am working on a Python program using sqlite3 that compares the hours billed to the hours on site for different employees, the code follows:

```
from dbConnect import db_connect


con = db_connect()
cur = con.cursor()


def hours_discrepancy():

    emp_ids_dict = [4759, 4477, 4475, 1230, 4479]
    continue_marker = "yes"
    chosen_date = input("Date: ")

    for i in emp_ids_dict:

        choose_emp = i
        # chosen_date = input("Date: ")

        emp_check = cur.execute(f"SELECT LastName, FirstName "
                                f"FROM BrandHours "
                                f"WHERE EmpID LIKE {choose_emp} AND Date LIKE {chosen_date}")
        emp_fetch = emp_check.fetchone()
        employee_name = str(emp_fetch[0] + ", " + emp_fetch[1])
        print(employee_name)

        reported = cur.execute(f"SELECT Reported, Punched "
                               f"FROM BrandHours "
                               f"WHERE EmpID LIKE {choose_emp} AND Date LIKE {chosen_date}")

        hours_fetch = reported.fetchone()

        reported_hours = hours_fetch[0]
        punched_hours = hours_fetch[1]

        print(reported_hours)
        print(punched_hours)

        discrepancy = reported_hours - punched_hours
        print(f"Discrepancy: {discrepancy}")
        print("=============================================================================")


hours_discrepancy()
```

I was having an issue in which only one employee would come up until, as you can see, I commented out the chosen_date input variable and moved in outside of the for loop.  Definitely it is better to have it outside of the loop, I see that now.  Still, the behavior with the date input inside of the loop was not what I expected.

My question is, why did the program merely return one employee, rather than asking for input "Date: " at each iteration?

EDIT: dbConnect is another script I have that this one calls to:

```
import os
import sqlite3


default_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'db.sqlite3')


def db_connect(db_path=default_path):
    con = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
    return con
```

Comment: I suspect using prepared statement placeholders instead of inserting arbitrary user-provided text directly into a query string will make a difference, as well as not opening you up to [sql injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Hey Shawn, thanks for the input, I know that if I ever released this to other users I would need to parameterize my queries, but at present this is just a tool I am developing to replace an MS Access one I use currently.  No outside access.  Still, a good point.  I'll test it out and see if it alters the surprising behavior I've been receiving.